# Typescript error when using React updater functions to update state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm setting a toggle with useState using updater functions to update the state.

https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state

I have this component

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState<boolean>(true);
...
<MyContainer handleToggle={setToggle}>
```

```
// MyContainer.tsx

type Props = {
  handleToggle: (value: boolean) => void;
};

export const MyContainer = ({handleToggle }: Props) => {
   ...
   // I call handleToggle this component like this
   handleToggle((prevState: boolean) => !prevState);
   ...
}
```

I'm getting this typescript error

```
(parameter) prevState: boolean
Argument of type '(prevState: boolean) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to use the type provided by the React package itself.

```
type Props = {
  handleToggle: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};
```

But a better approach could be to do it this way:

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState<boolean>(true);
...
<MyContainer handleToggle={()=>setToggle(prev=>!prev)}>
```

and then on your child component:

```
type Props = {
  handleToggle: VoidFunction;
};

export const MyContainer = ({handleToggle }: Props) => {
   ...
   just call handleToggle now.
   handleToggle();
   ...
}
```

In my opinion, Passing setter functions are bad since those make your components coupled and hard to re-use.

Answer (score 0):

`setToggle` expects a boolean but you're passing a function that returns a boolean

try to change
`handleToggle(prevState => !prevState);`
to
`handleToggle(!toggle);`